# Android - Software to capture/view phone's camera from PC

Tags: android, streaming, camera

The idea is very simple. You install a server on your phone, a client on your PC, and then you can view your phone's camera from PC. And of course, capture said source as well.

I had this setup with my very old Symbian phone, yet I struggle to find a similar solution for my Android phone.

I have [found an article about this](http://androidflip.com/how-to-use-android-webcam-pc-usb-wireless/), but the app mentioned on said article - has been removed since.
[IP Webcam](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pas.webcam&feature=search_result) works, but it is very slow. I have maxed out the bitrate settings and I have a strong wifi signal... yet I get only like 3-10 FPS if I view the video in 1080p.

I am looking for a way to ***capture the video feed from the camera.*** IP Camera is really a dream in every aspect - it works as a feed (OBS), in browser, from VLC. Really it is a great software. But wifi is a really limiting factor - unless the source is encoded on flight, ~5M/s is not enough for 1080p@30.

Comment: For screenshots, take a look at [snap-android](https://github.com/snapwire-media/snap-android). For video, I've not checked yet.

Comment: You might wish to update your question once more with a price tag (whether it must be free, or there's a budget). While waiting for the perfect answer, be welcome to check my list of apps on [Video Surveillance & WebCams](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/remotedroid_webcams). Good luck!